# Dynamic Temporal SQL Server 2005 Table by CASE

Tags: sql-server, case

I need to define temporal table depending of value of parameter, I put this code:

```
CASE @estadoFacturacion
        WHEN 1 THEN SELECT * INTO #EstadoFacturacion FROM f_lineas_proceso_pendiente(@custCod) --PROCESOS QUE NO TIENEN NINGUNA FACTURA ASOCIADA
        WHEN 2 THEN SELECT * INTO #EstadoFacturacion FROM f_lineas_proceso_FactParcial(@custCod) --PROCESOS CON, AL MENOS, 1 TRAMO FACTURADO
        WHEN 3 THEN SELECT * INTO #EstadoFacturacion FROM f_lineas_proceso_AbonoParcial(@custCod) --PROCESOS CON, AL MENOS, 1 TRAMO ABONADO
        WHEN 4 THEN SELECT * INTO #EstadoFacturacion FROM f_lineas_proceso_Facturada(@custCod) --PROCESOS CON TODOS LOS TRAMOS FACTURADOS
        WHEN 5 THEN SELECT * INTO #EstadoFacturacion FROM f_lineas_proceso_Abonada(@custCod) --PROCESOS CON TODOS LOS TRAMOS ABONADO
        ELSE SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, LP.fk_proyecto_id) + '-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,LP.linea) IdProyLinea INTO #EstadoFacturacion FROM lineas_proceso LP --TODOS LOS PROCESOS
```

But it doesn't works...

¿How can I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: CASE is not for control-of-flow; its an expression that must return a value; use IF/ELSE

Answer (score 1):

SQL server does not have a `CASE` *statement*, only a `CASE` *expression*. So use an `IF ELSE IF` ladder instead:

```
IF @estadoFacturacion = 1 
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    INTO #EstadoFacturacion
    FROM f_lineas_proceso_pendiente(@custCod)
END
ELSE IF @estadoFacturacion = 2
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    INTO #EstadoFacturacion
    FROM f_lineas_proceso_FactParcial(@custCod)
END
...
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, LP.fk_proyecto_id) + '-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,LP.linea) Id
    INTO #EstadoFacturacion
    FROM lineas_proceso LP
END
```

Comment: It doesn't work, return the following error 5 times: There is already an object named '#EstadoFacturacion' in the database.

Comment: That is a different question. The answer is: IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#EstadoFacturacion') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
 DROP TABLE #EstadoFacturacion
END

Comment: Doesn't work. When I try to compile the script, ever return that error. I'm try put your last script before IF, and in each ELSE IF block...